# RTF Editor That Separates the content from the RTF tags

Tags: editor, rtf

WordPerfect 5.1 had a split screen mode: WYSIWYG in the top panel, "markup" (i.e., formatting tags) in the bottom panel. Does anyone know of an editor which can do something similar for RTF files?

Comment: Recommendations for off-site resources are off topic here per the [help].